# Adding interface to wildfly

Tags: configuration, jboss, command-line-interface, wildfly

By changing the management and public interface to the host name in standalone.xml , we can allow remote access to wildfly. Want to do this directly without touching the standalone xml file.

Using wildfly cli interactive mode, added the following and it works well.

```
/interface=localHostName/:add(inet-address= "${jboss.bind.address.management:<hostname of target box>}")
```

Now, i want to add the same in cli non-interactive mode using the --command/--commands option

Tried this, but getting stuck at the syntax thing,

```
./jboss-cli.sh --connect command="/interface=localHostName/:add(inet-address="${jboss.bind.address.management:<hostname of target box>}")"
```

Please let me know the correct syntax of adding an inet-address to wildfly through command option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

actually this should work:

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c --command="/interface=localHostName:add(inet-address=${jboss.bind.address.management:<hostname of target box>})"
```

but I also get an error with the variable replacement. I checked it with this command and it worked:

```
./jboss-cli.sh -c --command="/interface=localHostName:add(inet-address=<hostname of target box>)"
```

I also had a glance at the jboss-cli.xml configuration file but the resolve-parameter-values property was already set to false so I don't know why the CLI is trying to replace this property.

The question is if you really need this property. I think you won't since you are setting it to the same property as the management-interface. So passing this property at startup will change both interfaces' inet-address values. I'm also setting the address using a CLI script and also omit the property since this interface's inet-address binding won't be changed for productional setup.

Comment: The second command(/interface=localHostName:add(inet-address=<hostname>)) is not working for me. It gives the following error,  Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("interface" => "localHostName")]) - failure description: "No interface criteria was provided"

Comment: When I run the command on Wildfly 8.1.0.Final I get no errors. I can either replace <hostname of target box> with the hostname or the IP address and everything works fine.

How is your setup? Which Wildfly version, fresh copy or pre-configured?

Comment: Thanks Shi, this cmd worked, 
./jboss-cli.sh --connect --command="/interface=localHostName/:add(inet-address="'${jboss.bind.address.management:<hostname>}'")"